# Why does the alignment of my elements shift left when screen size shrinks (using bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I think the best way to understand what is happening is by looking at pictures.

This is what I have it look like normally:

[image: This is what I have it look like normally]

This is what it looks like on smaller screens:

[image: and this is what it looks like on smaller screens]

On smaller screens I'd want it to just center the image and have the text underneath. I have tried using a flexbox and using align centre but it doesn't work. Here is my code for reference https://codepen.io/pierresarrailh/pen/MWoZMav

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div id="landing-page" class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">
  <div class="align-self-center col-lg-8">
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap row align-content-center">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <img id="profile-pic" src="https://picsum.photos/300" alt="Card image cap" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6" id="intro-text">
        <h2> Hi, Pleasure to meet you!</h2>
        <br>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam justo libero, malesuada nec imperdiet in, pharetra quis odio. Nullam aliquet orci ut lobortis commodo. Pellentesque et ligula ut nisi ultrices pellentesque.
        </p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems that the class "container" is used. In both screenshots the image is on the left side but on (extra) smaal screens the container has a width 100%, then you will see this effect most. Give the image a class `mx-auto` to center it

Answer (score 0):

try to keep the code more simple. As you can see, I am doing e.g. this "col-12 col-lg-8".
this basically do 100 % with on mobile and smaller on desktop.
also, do not use ID's for styling. They become too specific, and a meant for javascript and such.

try something like this
UPDATED answer

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
      <style>
        @media (max-width: 600px) {
          .image-container {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
          }
      }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="landing-page">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-8">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 image-container">
                  <img class="profile-pic" src="https://picsum.photos/300" alt="Card image cap" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 intro-text">
                  <h2> Hi, Pleasure to meet you!</h2>
                  <br>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam justo libero, malesuada nec imperdiet in, pharetra quis odio. Nullam aliquet orci ut lobortis commodo. Pellentesque et ligula ut nisi ultrices pellentesque.
                  </p>
          
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This is a much better approach but the image is not centered on small screens.

Comment: updated answer.